# Are SOA and Agile methodologies complimentary?

Tags: agile, soa

I haven't yet started learning either of the two, but I was wondering whether any of you use Agile methodologies to implement SOA?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working full time with SOA implementations, I have some experience regarding this.

You can use different methodologies to implement SOA into an organisation. I've seen no attempt to go in and in one single project remake the entire enterprise integration design to SOA. Rather, this will happend step by step once business requirements emerge or changes.

Often each sub project in a SOA implementation is rather small - often too small to divide into SCRUM sprints with production releases.

In many ways the Waterfall method is usually conceptually the easiest method to implement SOA. The specs of a service WILL CHANGE over time, but there is no way this can be planned into, say 6 months intervalls, since it's very much driven by business requirement changes or influenced by upgrades/exchanges of enterprise information systems.

However, when the design phase is done and specs + technology pattern is decided, there might be a decent amount of changes of the design spec. in a projects once the implementation phase has started. It is usually the case, from my experience, that once started to flip the stones, old and unknown thigns crawls up that requries changes. A more [iterative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development) approach will usually be cheaper than strict waterfall - however not necessairly an agile approach.

Another important factor to decide upon the methodology is the way projects are financed and setup. An agile approach might get better overall result/cash ratio, but that is only if your organisation can cope with agile methods. If you are working as internal contractors to enable SOA for some busines requirement, which I am used to, then a project plan might be setup, a cost estimate and a strict time schedule with responsibiltites. It's rather hard to hold such as schedule for every single project with an agile approach, specifically, it's hard to give clear cost estimates for small-medium SOA projects.

For larger SOA projects, delivered to a single owner, I've succesfully used SCRUM and really recommend it.

Comment: Would you agree that you should implement SOA using Agile methodologies only when you are already experienced/good at agile programming? Thus, would you recommend I write SOA using waterfall until I get good at agile programming?

Comment: It's not really as much about programming here and your skills (as a developer). I think you will be more productive if you can get an agile project up and running and the project is large enough). The important part for agile to work out is that the stakeholders accept it and feels good about it. I suppose you cannot just hack away but in the end, there is a business unit paying for the whole party that needs to be involved and active in an agile project.

Comment: thank you all for your kind help

Answer (score 6):

### So the question is: [Are SOA and Agile friends or foes?](http://www.infoq.com/articles/SOA-Agile-Friends-Or-Foes)

In summary, Service Oriented Architecture (SOA) and Agile software development both help companies become more flexible and better align business and IT. As a result, many have noted that SOA and Agile seem like a natural fit.

*SOA introduces a controlled environment in which changes are accommodated in support of Agile processes, where quality, efficiency and productivity are increased through the appliance of design patterns, standards and governance procedures. Design patterns like service reusability, composability and abstraction, to cite a few, are leveraged to provide flexible and adaptable ecosystems. Agile methods also enable the lifecycle to be more incremental and interactive, allowing the business to get/give faster feedback from/to IT. They both support the continuous business-IT cycle that is needed to allow businesses to set up strategies aligned with IT. --[What does SOA brings to Agile? Or Agile to SOA?](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/service-oriented/what-does-soa-bring-to-agile-or-agile-to-soa/8041)*

### Explanation

As you can see in the [SOA Manifesto 2009](http://www.soa-manifesto.org/) and [Agile Manifesto 2001](http://www.agilemanifesto.org/), there are plenty of common values, such as Agility, Flexibility, To see changes as oportunities and a lot more. Some see SOA as an evolution of Agile, due to Cloud Computing [2008], Web Services [2004] and so on. These people, who have written the manifestos, were unhappy with [Waterfall Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model) because the clients were unhappy due the limited software delivered. The clients couldn't change the requirements without burocracy and sometimes they only knew what they want or need in the middle of the process, in this time a contract had been already signed. It looked like  Fred Brooks, Jr said *"Plan to throw one [implementation] away; You will, anyhow!"*.

So the people started to make things in Agile way. And it brought happiness to clients. They, somehow, started to be satisfied by the software and the software was more accurate than ever, with minor bugs and according to the requirements.

With the distributed systems's BOOM!, in my opnion started with Google, some people start develop things on the internet, such as public or private web services and external API, and the good practice of SOA was buzz word. They wrote the manifesto and it became a major architectural design.

### Notes

1. Waterfall isn't bad or wrong! For some people like NASA, it still good, and it works well for important software that specs won't change.
2. There are much more architectural design patterns, such as Layers and so on. What you need to know is if this pattern fit into your project or not. Maybe SOA won't fit.
3. Futhermore, There is no silver bullet!

Comment: Waterfall actually is bad... organizations building high risk systems (such as NASA) would use the Spiral model, these days anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we do use Agile methodology to implement SOA powered projects. But there's no objection to not to use Agile methodology. I guess in some specific projects e.g. Defense Ministry or Highly Risk projects where Agile are not allowed due of hard control SOA used too. Because this terms are orthogonal.

Comment: Would you agree that you should implement SOA using Agile methodologies only when you are already experienced/good at agile programming? Thus, would you recommend I write SOA using waterfall until I get good at agile programming?

Comment: If you are going to implement project by yourself or it's not a high risky project you are free to use any approach you want because you are learning. I saw waterfall methodology used only in huge industry projects where billions are spent for developing specifications, diagrams and models with the total cost overhead and process is sluggish. I think you should go ahead and kill two birds with one stone.